# Unoptimized IEnumerable<>.Last with predicate

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

The `public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)` extension method for `IEnumerable<TSource>` uses optimization for a source of the `IList<TSource>` type so that it does not iterate over the whole sequence when it can just step at the end using indexing.

```
IList<TSource> tSources = source as IList<TSource>;
if (tSources != null)
{
    int count = tSources.Count;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        return tSources[count - 1];
    }
}
```

I slightly altered the code so that it is mroe readable, but the functionality remains the same.

Why is not `public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)` also optimized when it could clearly start iterating from the end of the sequence?

If there should be something that matches the predicate and it is near the start of the sequence then I still need to iterate to the very end. If there is something matching at the end I don't have to iterate more, because I started from the end.

I would expect something like this being a part of the method.

```
IList<TSource> tSources = source as IList<TSource>;
if (tSources != null)
{
    int count = tSources.Count;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (predicate(tSources[i]))
            {
                return tSources[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a number of optimizations that could be performed that aren't.  For example, `Reverse` could be optimized for lists, but isn't.  As with any other feature ever, the answer is either, they didn't think of the feature, or they didn't consider it worth taking the time to implement.

Comment: Hard to believe that. I'm working with .NET a few years now and I like it particularly because they do not release half-baked features. I even heard an interview with someone on the c# design team who even said the very sentence. Furthermore, they couldn't simply overlook this, when they optimized many more methods.

Comment: So you think the method is half baked just because it doesn't have this feature?  Realize that there are tens of thousands of proposed features for a language like C# that need to be rejected.  Only a very tiny fraction of features that are considered can ever be implemented.  There are *lots* of rejected features that could actually be reasonably helpful.  The team simply doesn't have unlimited resources.

Comment: Also note that this would change not just the performance, but how the method functions.  If the predicate has side effects you're changing which items have the predicate called on them, and in what order it's called.  That could be a problem (although hopefully people wouldn't rely on that).

Comment: Just for my own knowledge, what am I misunderstanding about this? It seems to me that you don't know if the last item satisfying the criteria will be at the start, or the end, and to find out which, you'll have to iterate through all the elements in any case. What did I miss?

Comment: @Servy Your last comment could be probably the reason. Nice point indeed!

Comment: @Chris Well, you are looking for the last item that meets the predicate. There can be more than one and you are interested in that that is closest to the end of the sequence.

Comment: Ah, I've been re-reading it for clarity. I'd slightly misunderstood what you were asking (about the source). Thanks =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, which is a shot in dark, as any answer you might get: optimizing in the predicate case would cause more side effects. Optimization generally causes a side-effect because the GetEnumerator() of IEnumarble is not called. But in the predicate case, you can observe from the outside that it's not called in order. One might write a predicate that expects the iteration to happen in order, and going backwards would break that.

Answer (score 0):

Except when an implementation of `IList<T>` contains a very small number of items, optimizing the non-predicate `Last` to return `theList[theList.Count()-1]` is unlikely to be slower than simply enumerating from the start; it's unlikely that for any reasonable `IList<T>` implementation it will be much slower.  Even though the time required for some implementations of `IList<T>` to find an item by index may be significantly longer than the average per-item time required to fetch data sequentially (perhaps by an order of magnitude, though probably not two), reading *one* item by index will generally take much less time than reading *every* item sequentially (random access generally won't be *much* slower than sequential access unless a collection is big; if in a 1,000,000-item collection the cost to read an item by index is 1,000 times the per-item time required for sequential access [an atypically-large penalty], that would still be 1,000 times as fast as reading every item).

When using `Last` with a predicate, there's no guarantee how many items will need to be examined.  If random access takes longer than sequential access (common), and the last match happens to occur early in the list (highly plausible), then processing the list from the start will be faster than processing from the end.  Given that it would not be unreasonable for an `IList<T>` implementation to take ten times as long to perform a random access as a sequential fetch, the "optimization" of reading from the back could end up making things an order of magnitude slower than "unoptimized" code that read sequentially.

If `IList<T>` provided more options for reading out data, and/or included properties which roughly described the relative costs of different operations, then a `Last` method could be optimized to examine list items in some other sequence, but absent such features it's better for the method to use a straightforward approach whose behavior is predictable if uninspiring, than one which tries to be clever but might sometimes perform much worse.